# Using Css calc() to align a Pseudo element to work all screen

Tags: html, css, sass, css-calc

so like the title says, i am trying to align the bullets to align in the center of the vertical grey line. I am kind of beginner with css and not 100% sure how calc() work even-thou i have successfully implemented in other places. Is this the right approach to do my alignments ? Using media query would be too much since there are too many break points and changing the html is not an option per design. One of the cal() function i successfully used was this:

> left: calc((100% - 3 * 11rem) * .54 - 4px)!important;

so i thought i can use the same formula then changing the values till the grey line aligns. Seems this thought was flawed

**Desired look**

[image]

**Current look**

[image]

**Here is my code:**

```css
html {
  font-size: 18px;
}
@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 540px;
 }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 720px;
 }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 960px;
 }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 1400px;
 }
}
h1, .h1 {
  font-size: 3.815rem;
}
h2, .h2 {
  font-size: 2.441rem;
}
h3, .h3 {
  font-size: 1.563rem;
}
h4, .h4 {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}
.project-methodology-wrap {
  padding: 5rem 0;
 /*========== Media queries ==========*/
}
.project-methodology-wrap .methodologyBullet::before {
  content: '';
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #d4272e;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 30px;
  left: 26px;
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
}
.project-methodology-wrap .methodologyBullet::after {
  content: '';
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background: #d4272e;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 30px;
  left: 33px;
  top: 2px;
}
.project-methodology-wrap .project-methodology-list.active .methodologyBullet {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.project-methodology-wrap .project-methodology-list.active .methodologyBullet::before {
  opacity: 1;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  left: 26px;
}
.project-methodology-wrap .project-methodology-list.active .methodologyBullet::after {
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  width: 21px;
  height: 21px;
  left: 28px;
}
.project-methodology-wrap .project-methodology-listCount, .project-methodology-wrap .methodologyBullet {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
.project-methodology-wrap .project-methodology-leftContent {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
.project-methodology-wrap .project-methodology-rightContent {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.project-methodology-wrap .project-methodology-rightContent:before {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  width: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f2f6;
  left: calc((100% - 3 * 5rem) * .54 - -2px)!important
}
.project-methodology-wrap .project-methodology-rightContent .project-methodology-list {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  padding-left: 80px;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}
.project-methodology-wrap .project-methodology-rightContent .project-methodology-list .project-methodology-listContent {
  opacity: 0.2;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  -webkit-transform: none;
  transform: none;
}
.project-methodology-wrap .project-methodology-rightContent .project-methodology-list.active .project-methodology-listContent {
  opacity: 1;
}

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style/index.css">


</head>

<body>
    
    <section class="project-methodology-wrap">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                    <div class="project-methodology-leftContent">
                        <div class="pr-5">
                            <h2>title</h2>
                            <p>
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi, eum deserunt perferendis asperiores esse temporibus est numquam repellat doloremque suscipit enim quod nisi nam cum ea quam expedita quidem velit.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <img class="img-fluid pt-5 pb-5 pr-5" src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/5x8p2z5cvip5u38/chicago.jpg?dl=1">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                    <div class="project-methodology-rightContent pt-5">
                            <div class="project-methodology-list">
                                <div class="methodologyBullet">&nbsp;</div>
                                <div class="project-methodology-listContent">
                                    <h4 class="project-methodology-listCount">1</h4>
                                    <h4>
                                       Title
                                    </h4>
                                    <p>
                                       Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam, enim nam! Quisquam aliquid, harum reiciendis deleniti minima natus veniam. Fuga sunt rerum adipisci at et ad repellendus sint velit ducimus.

                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="project-methodology-list">
                                <div class="methodologyBullet">&nbsp;</div>
                                <div class="project-methodology-listContent">
                                    <h4 class="project-methodology-listCount">2</h4>
                                    <h4>
                                       Title
                                    </h4>
                                    <p>
                                       Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam, enim nam! Quisquam aliquid, harum reiciendis deleniti minima natus veniam. Fuga sunt rerum adipisci at et ad repellendus sint velit ducimus.

                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="project-methodology-list">
                                <div class="methodologyBullet">&nbsp;</div>
                                <div class="project-methodology-listContent">
                                    <h4 class="project-methodology-listCount">3</h4>
                                    <h4>
                                       Title
                                    </h4>
                                    <p>
                                       Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam, enim nam! Quisquam aliquid, harum reiciendis deleniti minima natus veniam. Fuga sunt rerum adipisci at et ad repellendus sint velit ducimus.

                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
 
 

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: why `- -2px`? you can simply do `+ 2px`

Comment: @TemaniAfif true ,i was just copy pasting another calc() function i had and was adjusting the values on chrome inspector

Comment: also what is the logic of multiplying by `.54` ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif ah.. wish i had a logic, but truth is I simply copy pasted from a snippet that worked and never tried  to understand how calc works till now  :(.

Comment: well, they are doing maths (multiplication, addition, division), they aren't complicated but the value used need to have a meaning for your siutation

Comment: Can you just use a fixed value like left: 35px; instead of a complicated calc function? Is there a need for the calculation?

Comment: it's not responsive if i do that, media query was not a good solution due to too many break points @MarioD

Comment: @jsPlayer a fixed value works fine in the example above at all sizes. Do you have an example where the fixed value doesn't work that we could take a look at?

Comment: @MarioD ah i feel like a fool. Sorry i am a super beginner at css, I had initially put % instead of px and thought fixed value will not work.  why doesn't % work but px do ? . thanks for your answer, please put it as an answer and i will accept

Comment: @jsPlayer all good, happens to us all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like in this case you could get away with using a fixed value `left: 35px;` since the scale of the elements to the left of the dots does not change.

```css
html {
  font-size: 18px;
}
@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 540px;
 }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 720px;
 }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 960px;
 }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 1400px;
 }
}
h1, .h1 {
  font-size: 3.815rem;
}
h2, .h2 {
  font-size: 2.441rem;
}
h3, .h3 {
  font-size: 1.563rem;
}
h4, .h4 {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}
.project-methodology-wrap {
  padding: 5rem 0;
 /*========== Media queries ==========*/
}
.project-methodology-wrap .methodologyBullet::before {
  content: '';
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #d4272e;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 30px;
  left: 26px;
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
}
.project-methodology-wrap .methodologyBullet::after {
  content: '';
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background: #d4272e;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 30px;
  left: 33px;
  top: 2px;
}
.project-methodology-wrap .project-methodology-list.active .methodologyBullet {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.project-methodology-wrap .project-methodology-list.active .methodologyBullet::before {
  opacity: 1;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  left: 26px;
}
.project-methodology-wrap .project-methodology-list.active .methodologyBullet::after {
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  width: 21px;
  height: 21px;
  left: 28px;
}
.project-methodology-wrap .project-methodology-listCount, .project-methodology-wrap .methodologyBullet {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
.project-methodology-wrap .project-methodology-leftContent {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
.project-methodology-wrap .project-methodology-rightContent {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.project-methodology-wrap .project-methodology-rightContent:before {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  width: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f2f6;
  left: 35px;
}
.project-methodology-wrap .project-methodology-rightContent .project-methodology-list {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  padding-left: 80px;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}
.project-methodology-wrap .project-methodology-rightContent .project-methodology-list .project-methodology-listContent {
  opacity: 0.2;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  -webkit-transform: none;
  transform: none;
}
.project-methodology-wrap .project-methodology-rightContent .project-methodology-list.active .project-methodology-listContent {
  opacity: 1;
}

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style/index.css">


</head>

<body>
    
    <section class="project-methodology-wrap">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                    <div class="project-methodology-leftContent">
                        <div class="pr-5">
                            <h2>title</h2>
                            <p>
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi, eum deserunt perferendis asperiores esse temporibus est numquam repellat doloremque suscipit enim quod nisi nam cum ea quam expedita quidem velit.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <img class="img-fluid pt-5 pb-5 pr-5" src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/5x8p2z5cvip5u38/chicago.jpg?dl=1">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                    <div class="project-methodology-rightContent pt-5">
                            <div class="project-methodology-list">
                                <div class="methodologyBullet">&nbsp;</div>
                                <div class="project-methodology-listContent">
                                    <h4 class="project-methodology-listCount">1</h4>
                                    <h4>
                                       Title
                                    </h4>
                                    <p>
                                       Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam, enim nam! Quisquam aliquid, harum reiciendis deleniti minima natus veniam. Fuga sunt rerum adipisci at et ad repellendus sint velit ducimus.

                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="project-methodology-list">
                                <div class="methodologyBullet">&nbsp;</div>
                                <div class="project-methodology-listContent">
                                    <h4 class="project-methodology-listCount">2</h4>
                                    <h4>
                                       Title
                                    </h4>
                                    <p>
                                       Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam, enim nam! Quisquam aliquid, harum reiciendis deleniti minima natus veniam. Fuga sunt rerum adipisci at et ad repellendus sint velit ducimus.

                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="project-methodology-list">
                                <div class="methodologyBullet">&nbsp;</div>
                                <div class="project-methodology-listContent">
                                    <h4 class="project-methodology-listCount">3</h4>
                                    <h4>
                                       Title
                                    </h4>
                                    <p>
                                       Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam, enim nam! Quisquam aliquid, harum reiciendis deleniti minima natus veniam. Fuga sunt rerum adipisci at et ad repellendus sint velit ducimus.

                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
 
 

</body>

</html>
```